# Finding Maclaurin’s series expansion function of $f(x) = a^x$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

First derivation is easy as it's $a^x * \log a$, but I have some troubles with finding the derivative of $ a^x * \log a$

Using the product rule I have $ (a^x *\log a)' = (a^x * \log^2 a) + a^x * \frac{1}{a}$, whereas wolfram says it should be just $a^x * \log^2 a$.

Need a hint.

Comment: The answer below solves your problem with the 2nd differentiation, and for the whole work perhaps you may want to consider $\;a^x=e^{x\log a}\;$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Differentiation is with respect to  $x $.

Comment: Haha, that's a pretty useful hint, thank you

Answer (score 0):

We get $$(a^x)'=a^x\log(a)$$
$$(a^x\log(a))'=a^x(\log(a))^2$$
$$(a^x(\log(a))^2)'=a^x(\log(a))^3$$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
a^x=e^{x\log{a}}
$$
You know how to take derivatives of the exponential.